# How to call this.id in a $.get URL

Tags: javascript, php, button, get

I am trying to execute a javascript script but I am not sure how to do this. I usually work in PHP but for this specific thing I needed to implement some javascript. On my website I have a couple of buttons with different ID's. When a button gets pushed, a javascript will run. Inside the javascript the ID will be used to execute a php page. Right now I am using the button to delete a certain thing.

For instance, let's say I push the button with ID= 20. Then I would need the page to run the follow script:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.get("example.php?id=(this.id)");
});
```

As you can see I am trying to execute the page example.php?id=20 but this is somehow not working and I have no idea how I would fix this. Is there a different way to solve this problem? Btw, I use this as button

```
<button id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary sweet-4" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'example', 'try', 'sweet-4', 'this.id']);">Test</button>
```

There are some more things happening here, but the main thing I want happening is getting the ID. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have string interpolation (unless you use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but there's no IE support), so you will have to concatentate.

```
$.get("example.php?id=" + this.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("example.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside of quotes is interpreted as a String, not as a Javascript key word. It looks like you're trying to use parentheses to interpolate the string held in `this.id`. You can't do that in Javascript.

```
$.get("example.php?id=" + this.id );
```